# Wants to apply ID based lock in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am writing a c# class as below. I have roll number of the student as a unique key in a table is there any way I can lock based on rollNo, if modification from multiple threads with the same roll number is not allowed and with different roll number it should be allowed.

```
Class ABC 
{
    public Void UpdateStudent(int rollNo)
    {
        student = fetchRecord();

        if(some condtion)
        {
            //Update Student table
        }

        if(some condtion)
        {
            //Update Student table
        }

        if(some condtion)
        {
            //Update Student table
        }

        // enter code here
    }
}
```

Comment: What;s the range of values for `rollNo` ?

Comment: more than  0 to 10,000

Comment: You certainly could, but generally that's what the database is there for anyhow.

Comment: but the problem is I am caching read and write, sometimes one student read and another student of same roll number updates this creates a problem, caching new data will take a few seconds

Comment: Can you show the code that caches the reads and writes? Where are you storing the cached data?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a `Dictionary` of locks. So for each roll number, you have a lock object and then you use it for safely updating the table only on one thread at a time.

```
Class ABC 
{
    private Dictionary<int, object> locks = new Dictionary<int, object>();
    private object locks_lock = new object();

    private object GetLock(int rollNo)
    {
        object lock;
        lock(locks_lock) {
            // get the lock for the provided rollNo
            if(!locks.TryGetValue(rollNo, out lock)) {
                // the lock for this rollNo doesn't exist yet, create it now
                lock = new object();
                locks.Add(rollNo, lock);
            }
        }
        return lock;
    }

    public void UpdateStudent(int rollNo)
    {
        var student = fetchRecord();

        if(some condition) {
            lock(GetLock(rollNo)) {
                //Update Student table
            }
        }
        if(some condition) {
            lock(GetLock(rollNo)) {
                //Update Student table
            }
        }

        // enter code here ...

    }
}
```

Comment: This has a couple of problems though: (a) you need to lock the access to the dictionary as well (when you `Add` the "locks"). (b) by having a one-to-one relationship between rollNo and lock, you will keep an entry for a student (or the rollNo) as long as the instance of the outer class exists. Group rollNo into buckets and have a lock for each. This will lock "a group of students" at once, yes, but you won't have to keep an unbounded number of entries in the dictionary (for maybe, forever).

Comment: I fixed the (a) problem. Regarding the (b) problem: I don't think this is a problem memory-wise nor implementation-wise. Retrieving a value from the Dictionary is very fast, close to O(1).

Comment: Maybe, but there are other solutions that don't have that "problem" in the first place. YMMV of course.

Comment: This will work under the assumption that the "Student table" is a thread-safe container, so that it can be mutated by multiple threads in parallel. Which is unlikely IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You could hold locks with a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

```
public class ABC
{
    static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<object>> Locks = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<object>>();

    public void UpdateStudent(int rollNo)
    {

        lock (Locks.GetOrAdd(rollNo, _ => new Lazy<object>()))
        {
            // do work here
            Console.WriteLine("Updating student");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Locks.TryRemove(rollNo, out _);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Student updated");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: GetOrAdd is not thread-safe: https://andrewlock.net/making-getoradd-on-concurrentdictionary-thread-safe-using-lazy/

Comment: thanks for that. I was pretty sure I tested it, but can't remember how. I've applied the `Lazy` trick as suggested in the link